colcon build disable or hide warning: -Wunused-parameter
I have a lot of warning: unused parameter ‘’ [-Wunused-parameter] when running colcon build. Actually, so much so that I'm unable to see the error output, which is annoying for debugging.
I'm searching for the best practice to disable or hide this warning.

The solution that I have found is by using --cmake-args:
colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-w"

Which disables warning output.

The '--cmake-args' is the right option. But I'm general it's recommended to only turn off warnings in as little scope as possible. Versus turning all of them off so use '-Wno-unused-variable' instead of '-w'.
